# Has the SE blog moved on from Disqus?

Tags: discussion, comments, design, blog

On recent blog posts, the comments look pretty ugly:

> [image]
>
> [image]

- No borders ... it feels like no CSS has been applied at all. Look at how terrible the alignment for the input boxes is.
- No voting (and no way to flag for spam, but that's probably not that necessary)
- and the *Reply* link almost feels like it's a part of the next post.

It looks like SE has imported the comments on old posts from Disqus.

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We decided to remove the Disqus commenting system from our blog and revert back to the default Wordpress commenting system. We had originally been paying for the Premium version of Disqus so our users wouldn't see ads. Then Disqus decided to change our account without warning and turn the ads back on. It took far too long for them to remedy the issue and so we decided to pull the plug (in addition to many more reasons, which I won't go into here) :)

We realize the comments now look less-than-ideal, and there is a ticket in with our dev team to edit the CSS for the blog. Granted, they have higher priorities right now so it may be a few days before it's cleaned up.

Comment: You can, and should, file a lawsuit against Disqus for changing the account without warning. That's beyond ugly, that's illegal.

Comment: [*a few days*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since they switched over to wordpress - they don't need a third party comments module Jekyll needed. Considering the entire point of moving over to a managed wordpress instance was *simplicity* - getting the vendor running the blog to maintain a plugin likely makes no sense.

The design itself? eh, yeah, it *is* somewhat ugly ;p